# Issue with for loop not being able to print user data

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop, methods

I'm having a problem where my for loop is not working, it seems that my pointer to the Applicant class isn't working, or the vector isn't holding any data and therefore just skips the loop and returns back to the previous method.

Below is the current class I'm working with and the for loop in which I'm having the problem. In theory I'm not entirely sure what's causing this.

```
Applicant applicant;
void viewApp(Applicant& applicant);

void viewApp(Applicant& applicant)
{
    cout << "ERROR!\n" << endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < applicant.thing.size(); i++)
    {
            cout << "Application Details:\n"
                 << "====================\n";
            cout << "Username: " << applicant.thing[i].getUserName() << endl;
            cout << "Password: " << applicant.thing[i].getPassword() << endl;
            cout << "First Name: " << applicant.thing[i].getFirstName() << endl;
            cout << "Second Name: " << applicant.thing[i].getSecondName() << endl;
            cout << "Email: " << applicant.thing[i].getEmail() << endl;
            cout << "Application Status: " << applicant.thing[i].getStatus() << endl;
            cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks.
Tom

Comment: `my for loop is not working, it seems that my pointer to the Applicant class isn't working, or the vector isn't holding any data and therefore just skips the loop and returns back to the previous method.` This is two totally different theories. You can, right now, on your own, _test_ to find out which is in force here. Why not do that? Also, you have no pointers here, and we don't know how you're calling this function. Present a [testcase](http://sscce.org) when you need help. I'm fairly sure I've said this to you before. _What is your actual output and your desired output? You never said._

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've done much debugging on your own if you don't know if the loop ever executes.  Set a breakpoint, step through the code, and analyze variable states.  Debuggers are your friend.

Comment: Okay sorry about the post, After looking through my code I noticed my vector holds data correctly. Now its to figure out why the for loop isn't running.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the for statement is skipped over. It seems to return the length of the vector as 0 and therefore just skips through it.

Comment: Back to what I said about testcases. There is not enough to go on here. You're probably passing a different, empty vector in.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not 100% sure on this, but I think when it returns back to main menu after `code`thing.push_back(applicant)`code` it deletes the data. I have debugged this multiple times and just going through each statement I know that the for loop is being skipped because the applicant is matching 0, but other than that. I simply have no idea.

Comment: Post. A. Testcase. What is confusing about these words? Or are you ignoring me deliberately? Also, I just gave you a good idea.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm sorry I've not done a Testcase before. However with my best attempt after following the link you gave, here's the attempt. Please tell me if anything is missing.
http://pastebin.com/2Xp8qsWv

Comment: @TomCummins: It's better. Almost there. You have an `include`/`#include` typo, some headers referenced that don't exist, `Applicant` isn't defined, and you can merge the code into _one_ file, with a `main`, so that it can be executed.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you for your help and support. Here is an updated testcase.
http://pastebin.com/A0QE4cMN

Answer (score 1):

With your testcase (slightly adjusted to hard-code input rather than requiring user input, which is tricky on a live demo!), I can now [reproduce this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8aa8f6810dfc753f).

Your problem is in `createApplicant()`, where you create a *new* `Applicant` and pass a reference to it into `viewApplicant()` — but you never `push_back()` into that `Applicant` instance.

You are, in general, creating `Applicant` instances in places where you shouldn't. In particular, `createApplicant()` and `viewApplicant()` are both member functions, so you should be making use of `this` inside those.

I would suggest reading again the chapters in your book about the design of classes, how to pass objects between functions most effectively, and what should/should not be a member function.

As a design consideration, I'm more than a little confused as to why `Applicant` contains a vector of `Applicant`s. That is not entirely unprecedented, but it does seem quite strange to say the least (especially with such a descriptive name as `thing`, and *zero* documenting comments!).

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I have got the 'View Applicant UserName' to display in the testcase. However, when I try to use the following in my program I get an error in a switch menu where the method is called.
`code`Error 1 error C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member functions.

Comment: @TomCummins: `this` is used _inside_ member functions. Not when you call them from outside the class. Which C++ book are you using?

Comment: Have two currently: Walter J. Savitch Problem Solving with C++ & Scott Meyers Effective C++